# The set of points where an arbitrary function $f$ defined in a set $X \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ admits a strict maximum or minimum is enumerable.

Tags: real-analysis

The set of points where an arbitrary function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in a set $X \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ admits a strict maximum or minimum is enumerable.

[Let $E \subset X$ be a dense enumerable subset. For each point $x \in X$ that is a strict maximum of $f$, choose $e_{x} \in E$ and $r_{x} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|e_{x} - x| <r_{x}$ and $y \in B(e_{x}; r_{x}) - \{x\} \Rightarrow f(y) < f(x)$. The application $x \mapsto (e_{x}, r_{x})$ is injective].

I have tried to do this exercise absurdly, assuming it is not enumerable, but it is a bit difficult. I would like to know if there is a simpler way to solve this problem.

Comment: If $A$ is the set of points where $f$ attains a strict local maximum, then for every $x\in A$ there is $\delta_x>0$ such that $f(y)<f(x)$ for all $0<|y-x|<\delta_x$. In particular, there is no other point of $A$ inside the open boxes $\{y:\ |y-x|<\delta_x\}$. The open boxes $\{y:\ |y-x|<\delta_x\}$ are disjoint and open. Therefore, inside each we can place a point with rational coordinates. Because the boxes are disjoint, points chosen in different boxes will be different. The points with rational coordinates are countable.

Comment: Therefore, the map $x\in A$ sent to its box, sent to its chosen point with rational coordinates, is an injection from $A$ to a countable set.

Comment: I have two questions: why inside each one can we place a point with rational coordinates? And why are points with rational coordinates countable? I have not understood that part. Could you explain to me please.

Comment: The points with rational coordinates are dense, therefore inside each open set you can find one of them. The density of those points is ultimately a consequence of the property that between any two real numbers you can find a rational number. The countability of the points with rational coordinates is a consequence of rational numbers being countable, which imply that $m$-tuples of them are also countable. You can find proof of all of these in this site, for more details.

Comment: in conclusion it should be shown that the map $g: A \to \mathbb {Q^m} $ given by $ g (x) = (r_ {1}, r_ {2}, ..., r_ {m}) $, where every $ r_ {i} \in \mathbb{Q} $, is it injective?

Comment: I have the following test, but I don't know if I had an error:   Let $M$ be the set of strict local minima of a function $f$. Then for every $p\in M$ there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $f(p)$ is smaller than $f(x)$ for any $x\in(a,b)\setminus\{p\}$. We can now choose rational numbers $a_p,b_p$ with $a<a_p<p<b_p<b$, and $f(p)$ will be the smallest value on $(a_p,b_p)$.

Comment: Define a map $g:M\rightarrow\Bbb Q^2$ taking $p$ to a pair $(a_p,b_p)\in\Bbb Q^2$ like above (we don't need choice; we can choose $(a_p,b_p)$ to be the least working pair in some well-ordering of $\Bbb Q^2$). It's clear $g$ is injection, since $f(x),f(y)$ cannot both be smaller than each other for $x\neq y$. Hence $g$ is an injection into a countable set showing $M$ is countable.